# latex equation display in vim

Tags: vim, latex

I recently use the vim to write the latex source. But I got a very strange problem. When I open a old .tex file with vim, the equation will not show as usual. For example, when I type $K$, it just display K unless I move cursor to the line of the equation. And this does not happen when I open a new .tex file. Can anyone help? Thank.

Comment: You have a latex package/plugin installed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you see the effects of the *conceal* feature; the Tex syntax plugin uses that do shorten certain sequences for display. See `:help tex-conceal` for the full explanation of that feature.

If this annoys you, just disable concealing, e.g. via

```
:set conceallevel=0
```

Comment: Glad I could help. Please accept my answer by clicking on the outlined arrow next to it!